# HOW TO PERFORM BELOW EXCEL FUNCTION IN PYTHON (if function inside if function)

Tags: python, if-statement

**=IF(C2<>C1,"",IF(J2=J1,"","dif"))**
**I have tried below code but still iam not getting accurate output**
How to perform above excel formula in python.

```
data['d'] = data['C'].shift(1)==data['C']
data['d'] = data['C'].shift(1)==data['C']
data['d'] = data['d'].replace(False,'0')
data['d'] = data['d'].replace(True,'1')
data['e'] = data['J'].shift(1)==data['J']
data['e'] = data['e'].replace(False,'1')
data['e'] = data['e'].replace(True,'2')
data['K'] = data['d'] == data['e']
data['K'] = data['K'].replace(False,' ')
data['K'] = data['K'].replace(True,'dif')
```

Comment: Please read the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) for ```if``` statements, then post your attempt.

Comment: On stack overflow it's appreciated if you make an honest attempt to solve the problem first and show us what you're stuck on

Comment: #I have tried this method but still I am not getting the accurate output as excel
**K=IF(C2<>C1,"",IF(J2=J1,"","dif"))**

data['d'] = data['C'].shift(1)==data['C']
data['d'] = data['d'].replace(False,'0')
data['d'] = data['d'].replace(True,'1')

data['e'] = data['J'].shift(1)==data['J']
data['e'] = data['e'].replace(False,'1')
data['e'] = data['e'].replace(True,'2')

data['K'] = data['d'] == data['e']
data['K'] = data['K'].replace(False,' ')
data['K'] = data['K'].replace(True,'dif')

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are new to python otherwise you would not have posted such a question.

But essentially, you can implement this very quickly:

To understand this you need to learn about:

1. python operators (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp)
2. python if-else statements (https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp)

```
# if condition (IF(C2<>C1)
if C2 != C1:
    # value if true ("")
    print("")
# value if false
else:
    # if condition (IF(J2=J1)
    if J2 == J1:
        # value if true ("")
        print("")
    # value if false ("dif"))
    else:
        print("dif")
```

There is a much more efficient way to do this, but this should help.